# Android Close dataBase Failed

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

with simple below code i get this error for close `database` or `cursor`:

```
Database﹕ close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/ir.tsms/databases/tsms'
    android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException:
```

My Function:

```
public Boolean searchLastID( Long lastID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE + " WHERE lastId = ?" ;
    String[] args = {String.valueOf(lastID)};
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, args);
    //db.close();
    return cursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

after uncommenting `db.close();`

```
Cursor﹕ Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/ir.tsms/databases/tsms, table = null, query = SELECT * FROM ReceiveFields WHERE lastId = ?
```

whats problem and how to resolve that? i can't find any document about this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make your cursor a global variable
and inside your onDestory Method close your cursor and your database

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you're done retrieving the data of your query from your database you should **close** the `Cursor` **or** at least **deactivate it**. *(Keyword: Freeing resources)*

Following two quotes from the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html#close%28%29) on the `close()` and `deactivate()` method:

#### #close()

> Closes the Cursor, **releasing all of its resources** and making it
>   completely invalid. Unlike deactivate() a call to requery() will not
>   make the Cursor valid again.

#### #deactivate()

> Deactivates the Cursor, making all calls on it fail until requery() is
>   called. **Inactive Cursors use fewer resources** than active Cursors.
>   Calling requery() will make the cursor active again.